# Will the UK deny my entry because of too many successive visits?

Tags: visas, uk, us-citizens, study

I am a 20 year old American university student. I have a boyfriend who is a Scottish national. I traveled to the UK on March 16th to March 24th and from June 25th to August 10th. Now, I am planning to study abroad in the fall semester from Sept. 4th to January 7th. This puts me at just about 6 months of UK travel. I plan on getting a short term student visa at the border (a stamp on my passport that states that I am a short term student).

I have my UK university unconditional offer letter, proof of UK accommodation, proof of return flight, proof of finances, proof of enrollment at my home university, and an acceptance letter to an American dental school (proof I have plans in the US)

Is it likely that the UK will deny me because they will think I'm trying to establish residency in the UK? What will I do if they deny me?

Comment: "I plan on applying for a short term student visa at the border." If you had more time I would have suggested doing this while still in the US at the UK consulate. I don't think they'll deny you for no reason. You were a genuine visitor during those times and are a genuine student now.

Comment: You appear to have the proof required to qualify for a short term study stamp https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/usa/study/six_months_or_less If they deny you, you’ll have to return home.